# Border Rendering Is Not Supported By Sequencer

Tags: rendering

best to you all, please help me:

- My computer: iMac 21.5 inch)
- Environment: MacOS Monterey 12.7.3
- Blender 3.6.5
- working in this excellent program: Since 7 months ago

Photo of my screen:
[image: screenshot]

**Action:** As usual without problems till today I tried my
￼  see informations:

**Problem:** No render animation but a note saying that border rendering is not supported by sequencer

Possible solutions I tried under suggestions:

- I used the two commands *Render Region* and *Crop to Render Region*, and tried without.
- I moved reducing and increasing percentage in resolution
- I used the *Option B*

All without success to establish the order in this, nothing! Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What happens if you uncheck _Render Region_ and _Crop to Render Region_ below the _Format_ settings?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: “I tried my see informations.” What? I think you accidentally edited out some of the question while trying to add details.

Comment: What is *Option B*?